# Linkedin - How can i get big profile picture

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to harvest some profile photo's
which is no problem
after authentication an array is returned and i can use the value of 'pictureUrl' which contains the location of the small profile photo.

What i can't seem to find in the documentation is the url for the larger profile photo (which is shown after clicking on the small photo of a person's page)

Does anybody know how/where to get this bigger picture?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can get the original profile picture from here:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)?oauth2_access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Be careful about the special characters into the url (**::()**)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLinkedInProfilePhoto() {
IN.API.Raw("/people/~/picture-urls::(original)").result(function(result, metadata) 
{
   $('#image').attr("src", result.values);
}); 
   }
```

Comment: Please elaborate. An "answer" with uncommented, unexplained code is very rarely helpful for anyone.